# Error while creating stream on a table in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on stream source without CHANGE_TRACKING enabled

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If change tracking hasn't been enabled explicitly by the table owner role, then only the table owner role may create the stream.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stream.html#usage-notes

Either use the role that owns the table to create the stream or have the owning role enable change tracking for you.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for the solution. We are using replication tool with a role associated to it to load data into tables. Should we explicitly  grant ownership to new the role which we are using to create streams? or GRANT Usage on Schema <schema_name> to role <role_name> works?